# Variable transformation to deal with its skewness BUT with the second derivative of the wanted sign

Tags: data-transformation, skewness, derivative

Is it possible (how?) to find a functional form that deals with (right or positive) skewness of an explanatory variable but that satisfies particular properties for the second partial derivative of the response variable with respect to the transformed explanatory variable?

For example,
let have a regression function of 
$Y = alpha \times f(X) + \text{other variables} + e$

I know that $dY/df(X) <0$ (always), but I also want to have $d^2Y/df(X)^2 < 0$ due to the underlying theory for this relationship. Thus, a logarithmic, square root or reciprocal transformation of X does not fit as it results in the positive second derivative (that is a contradiction to the theory in my case).

Non-transformed data (in a linear form) yield otherwise very imprecise results for the model fit (in nonparametric regression setting, i.e. locally linear function).